# How to rotate Widgets in the FLUID gui editor

Tags: c++, widget, rotation, fluid, fltk

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/fltk.pdf) (page 98) and i'm having a lot of trouble. It seems to be a bit dated or something, but what is troubling me at the moment is that it tells me to

```
add the following to the CubeViewUI
constructor:
• A horizontal roller named hrot
• A vertical roller named vrot
• A horizontal slider named xpan
• A vertical slider named ypan
• A horizontal value slider named zoom
```

and doesn't say how, just showing a picture on how it should look when i'm finished.

**I'm looking all through the properties page of my hrot roller but can't find any option to make it horizontal. How do i do this??**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under properties, click the C++ tab, and in the upper right,
there's a chooser for Vertical and Horizontal.